# Center two absoluted <p>s within a section

Tags: html, css

Pretty simple question, but I can't seem to find a way to do it. Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/agreyfield91/x72qhe15/4/

```
.textwrap {
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 }
```

I've tried to use the translate method, but it didn't work.

Comment: You are required to place your markup that shows the problem here, not a jsfiddle which can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to absolutely position `.textwrap` and add `position: relative` to `.container`

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

.textwrap {
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="textwrap">
    <p>Center me</p>
    <p>Center me</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

You could also do it with flexbox.

```css
.container {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="textwrap">
    <p>Center me</p>
    <p>Center me</p>
  </div>
</section>
```